# Controlling iteration order in numpy ndarray subclasses

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to implement a ragged/jagged array as an ndarray subclass. The idea is that the actual array is actually a concatenated block of all the jagged rows, and calls to (for example) `__getindex__` and `__setindex__` are intercepted by the subclass and converted appropriately. This works wonderfully, as do ufuncs.

[image: a picture comparing the memory layout of the actual array to my proposed ragged array interface]

However, when I try to, for example, use `np.where`, it returns the coordinates of the underlying concatenated array, and I cannot figure out how to change this. My thoughts were:

- somehow change the behavior of the iterator that `where` uses--although it appears overloading `__iter__` does not change how `where` gets its iterator (this is deep in the numpy C).
- somehow, after where has run, intercept the coordinates that are coming out of where and convert them

Unfortuantely, after a few hours of digging around in the numpy code and reading the "subclassing ndarray" article, I cannot figure out how to do either of these things. Pure-python solutions are preferred but at this point, I am open to doing stuff in C as well.

Comment: The easy fix here is to not use `np.where(x)`, but use `np.nonzero(x)` instead, which is the same but works on subclasses, and calls `x.nonzero()`, which you can overload

Comment: That's a great idea! Although ideally I'd support as much of the numpy API as possible, I don't mind leaving bits off (reshape, for example). Can you think of a way to prevent `np.where` from silently generating wrong results (i.e. throwing an exception or warning)?